# Malcev's paper "On a class of homogeneous spaces" in English

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, nilpotent-groups

I am struggling to find the English translation of Malcev's paper "On a class of homogenous spaces" providing foundational material for nil-manifolds. To be precise this paper: *Malcev, A. I. On a class of homogeneous spaces. Amer. Math. Soc. Translation 1951, (1951). no. 39, 33 pp.* ([mathscinet link](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=39734)) . It would be really important, for a project I am doing, to find this paper and I did not succeed neither on the website of the AMS nor by standard googling, which gives tons of papers referring to it.

Can anyone provide a reference to a place where to download the paper? I am at an institution with free access virtually everywhere, I just need a place with the actual paper in English (yeah in Russian I could find it).

Comment: A good account of Mal'cev's work is in "Discrete Subgroups of Lie Groups" by M. S. Raghunathan which is probably in your library.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thanks a lot! I could indeed obtain this morning a copy of this one; and in Chapter 2 it indeed contains an account of Malcev's work. I will use this reference. I would still be glad to find Malcev's original work, but with some luck this reference might be already enough for the math.

Comment: There is no (nowhere!) English translation of this article. But in this article there are many interesting details not mentioned in Ragunathan's book. So try reading Russian. Sometimes it is useful :-)

Comment: I hope there will be once complete works of Malcev published in English!

Comment: The Russian original is easy to find (http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3161&option_lang=eng); try DeepL on it.

Answer (score 5):

This place is the interlibrary loan of your institution

Comment: Well thanks for the advice, I did not know this "interlibrary loan" business but I had in mind to talk on Monday with the local librarian. Anyhow, thanks to Igor's very useful comment above this might not be so necessary anymore: though I am still quite impressed by how difficult is to find this translation, given how relatively recent this work is.

Comment: @Tom1990 The ILL service is quite efficient, and nowadays they very often send you just the file with a scan.

Answer (score 0):

[The Russian original](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/f4bbcad8dff13663fdc1e07b7d350dd1/im3161.pdf):

You can use [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) to translate it, for free.
Here is a DeepL translation of the title and the abstract, to show how well it works:

*Izvestiya ACADEMY Nauke USSR Matematicheskaya Series 13 (1949), 9-32 A. I. MALTSEV ON ONE CLASS OF ONE-STANDING SPACES (Edited by Academician A. N. Kolmogorov)  I. MALCEV ON ONE CLASS OF ONE-LINE SPACE (Edited by Academician A. N. Kolmogorov) We consider a manifold with a transitive nilpotent topological group acting on it.  These manifolds can be dissolved into the topological product of Euclidean manifold and compact manifold" having the same property.  Compact manifolds on which nilpotent groups act transitive are uniquely defined by their fundamental groups, and an abstract group % is the fundamental group of a compact manifold with a transitive nilpotent group if and only if Ъ is a nilpotent group without elements of finite order with a finite number of generators*

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Obviously you need to work a little on it, but I think you can read it.